# a function to return a value/list of values from a given dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, get, key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the key from a given name in dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527285/how-to-get-the-key-from-a-given-name-in-dictionary-in-python)

I have a variable called

```
anime_dict
```

which contains a dictionary of lists of objects as shown below.

```
{'JI2212': ('Inu Yasha', [('year', 1992), ('rating', 3)]), 'EH389J': ('Naruto', [('year', 1994), ('rating', 4), ('readers', 3424322)]), 'PPP67': ('Fruits Basket', [('Year', 1999), ('rating', 5), ('readers', 434232), ('chap', 40)])}
```

so the key of the dict is the 1st part ('JI2212' for Inu Yasha), the 2nd part is the name and the last part contains a list of parts.
I want to swap the key and the value name so it would look like this.

```
{'Inu Yasha': ('JI2212', [('year', 1992), ('rating', 3)]), 'Naruto': ('EH389J', [('year', 1994), ('rating', 4), ('readers', 3424322)]), 'Fruits Basket': ('PPP67', [('Year', 1999), ('rating', 5), ('readers', 434232), ('chap', 40)])}
```

then i would need to write a function get_key so that when i enter the value name which is now the key, it would return the original key ('EH389J' for Naruto)

 and another function get_parts that will give the subparts ( [('year', 1992), ('rating', 3)]) from the given key name
also if there is no key exists then it would return 'Do not exist'

example:

```
>>>get_key('Inu Yasha')
'JI2212'
>>>get_parts('Inu Yasha')
[('year', 1992), ('rating', 3)]
>>>get_key('Nana')
'Do not exist'
```